# Find the rank of matrix

Tags: matrices

[image]

I feel that answer should be $1$ because if we take all elements except $1$ to be $0$, then rank is $1$ and only **option $\bf A$** contains $1$.

But do we have a proper method to solve these kind of problems ?

Comment: You could have texted me this question! This matrix can't have full rank, but I can't justify it. I'll have to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [Gramian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix), where the inner product $\langle p, q\rangle$ in question is just the dot product $p \cdot q$. In particular, if we let
\begin{align*}
v_1 &= (x_1, y_1) \\
v_2 &= (x_2, y_2) \\
v_3 &= (x_3, y_3) \\
v_4 &= (x_4, y_4),
\end{align*}
then your matrix becomes
$$\begin{pmatrix}
v_1 \cdot v_1 & v_1 \cdot v_2 & v_1 \cdot v_3 & v_1 \cdot v_4 \\
v_2 \cdot v_1 & v_2 \cdot v_2 & v_2 \cdot v_3 & v_2 \cdot v_4 \\
v_3 \cdot v_1 & v_3 \cdot v_2 & v_3 \cdot v_3 & v_3 \cdot v_4 \\
v_4 \cdot v_1 & v_4 \cdot v_2 & v_4 \cdot v_3 & v_4 \cdot v_4
\end{pmatrix}.$$
The rank of a Gramian is the dimension of the span of the vectors, i.e. the largest number of linearly independent vectors one can extract from the list.

Obviously, in this case, each vector belongs to a $2$-dimensional space $\Bbb{R}^2$ (or $\Bbb{C}^2$). The possible dimensions of their span are the possible dimensions of subspaces of $\Bbb{R}^2$: $0$, $1$, or $2$. Now, $0$ is actually excluded, since this would imply that every single vector must be the $0$ vector, a possibility that was explicitly excluded. So, the answer is $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The given matrix equals $$
\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\\y_3\\y_4\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}y_1&y_2&y_3&y_4\end{pmatrix}
$$
Each summand is of rank at most $1$, and since $$\operatorname{rank}(A+B)\leq\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(B)$$ the rank of the sum is at most $2$.  The rank is not $0$ since not all of the variables are $0$.

Comment: You have your matrix multiplications backwards; you're producing a $1 \times 1$ matrix.

Comment: @user744868 Duh.  Thank you.